# how compare 3 datetime together in mql4

Tags: datetime, mql4

i need compare 3 datetime together.
for example my datetime T1& T3 is in H1 timeframe and datetime T2 is on daily time frame 
know how can i check T2 between T1 @ T3
(in Mql4 programming)
tnx.

Comment: If `T1` and `T3` are your indexes, you can obtain time by calling `datetime timeT1=iTime(Symbol(),PERIOD_H1,T1);` If T1 is time already, it does not depend much on timeframe, and it is of type `int` so you can do any operations as you do with `int's`. `if(T1<T2 && T2<T3){}` is your condition.

Comment: tnx ser. we can get candle price with specefic time? for example i set time and resive price in this time?

Comment: What kind of price do you need? if `Ask` or `Bid` - only current. If Open or HLC, then you can ask for a specific M1 candle. `datetime time=D'2018.16.10 11:14; int shift=iBarShift(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1, time); double open=iOpen(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,shift);` and same using `iHigh(), iLow(), iClose()` functions

Comment: yes
but i need drow line with 2 point 
first point in High of each day and second point its on next day 
but my lenght of line is specific and its is equal one day 
in my pervios code i have got problem
my code because i need drow line in M1 TimeFrame and i cant drow this line.

Comment: for( int i=1 ; i<300 ; i++ ){
P1 = iHigh( Symbol(), PERIOD_D1, i );
T1 = iTime( Symbol(), PERIOD_D1, i );
T2 = iTime( Symbol(), PERIOD_D1, i-1 );//i cant close time of day because get open time of next candle
Trend_Line( 0 , "Line_Movarab_Up_High_"   + IntegerToString(i) , 0 , T1 , P1 , T2 , P1+(300*Point) ,clrGreen );
}

Comment: Your question was about datetime in MQL. If you have question about drawing objects on chart - open another question and show what you did and why you are not satisfied with the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

1.you can simply compare 3 datetimes: if (T2 > T1 && T2 < T3)
2.more exactly you can all translate them to hours by TimeHour(T1) function or more exactly TimeMinute() TimeSecond() function

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Flag = (T2 > T1 && T2 < T3)
```

If they should be in same day like this:

T1 = 2018.10.25 12:00
T3 = 2018.10.25 20:00

Then T3 is 2018.10.25 because it is daily time. You can compare their like below:

```
Year1 = TimeYear(T1);
Month1 = TimeYear(T1);
Week1 = TimeWeek(T1);
Day1 = TimeDay(T1);
Hour1 = TimeHour(T1);
Minute1 = TimeMinute(T1);
...
```